# What happens if you cheat at poker?

Tags: mass-effect-andromeda

Gil has invited me to play Poker with him, and I have the opportunity to have SAM assist with navigating through these cut scenes so that I win, or I can play without assistance and lose.

Other than the obvious immediate dialogue changes, what happens if you cheat at poker? What happens if you don't admit you've cheated?

Comment: My guess would it could impact romance but I don't see anything confirming it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't finished the game yet, and I haven't attempted to pursue a romance with Gil. But, I have played for 8+ hours since legitimately using my technologically enhanced senses to get a better read on my opponent.

The only noticeable results have been in dialog. For instance, we had a discussion about how the people of the Initiative need to reproduce. During that discussion, his friend Jill came up. He says (paraphrased)

> You remember her, I mentioned her when you were kicking my butt at poker.

At no point has he indicated any suspicion regarding how I was able to win.

Comment: not cheating at poker leads to a rather humorous dialog line later too

Comment: So you get away with it if you hide the fact? Hmm